# Server side html5 posting?

Tags: javascript, php, html, server-side

I'm trying to put 2 page up on a server and have 1 page read/write to the other.

example:
page 1: put "test" in the form.
page 2: displays "test". If anyone tries to access it, it displays "test".
for this reason, I couldn't use simple javascript and php that I know of.

I started googling some ways to do this and see html5 server sent event, but not sure how to go about it. Can someone help me?

Thanks

Edit: Adding code that I've tried

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>HTML5 Server-Sent Events</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){
        var source = new EventSource("server_time.php");
        source.onmessage = function(event){
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "New time received from web server: " + event.data + "<br>";
        };
    };
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="result">
        <!--Server response will be inserted here-->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now this reads from server_time.php but server_time automatically gets the time from the server. I'm not sure how to go about this. This might not be the right approach to what I'm trying to do.

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/1011527)

Comment: @JayBlanchard I'm not entirely sure what to write. I'm asking more about what method to go about rather than is my code wrong, because I don't even know whether html5 is the correct approach to this.

Comment: @Archie edit your question and add your php code & html code